# Adding a Func to an ExpandObject as Dictionary

Tags: c#

So I know how to add properties to an `ExpandoObject` as a dictionary, but I'm not sure how to add `Func`'s:

For example:

```
var foo = (IDictionary<string, object>)new ExpandoObject();
foo.Add("Bar", "SomeValue");
```

is fine. However I'm not sure how I'd then go on to add

```
foo.Add("FooFunc", (someString) =>
{
    return someString;
});
```

as its not an object. Any help appeciated, thanks in advance

Comment: How would the compiler know someString is supposed to be a string ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Func`s are objects but you may have to be explicit about adding one:

```
foo.Add("FooFunc", new Func<string, string>(someString => {
    //...
    return someString;
});
```